# Disable changing number when i click on it

Tags: jquery

I need to make a game called yathzee, when i roll the dices for the first time i get a output with the total numbers combined. But when i click on a dice i need to lock it so if i click on roll again that number stays the same.

This is the code i have

```
function randomGetal() {
    var getal = Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1);
    return getal;
}

$(document).ready(function ()
{
$('#werp1').click(function ()
    {
        $('#d1').html(randomGetal());
        $('#d2').html(randomGetal());
        $('#d3').html(randomGetal());
        $('#d4').html(randomGetal());
        $('#d5').html(randomGetal());

        var d1 = $('#d1').html();
        var d2 = $('#d2').html();
        var d3 = $('#d3').html();
        var d4 = $('#d4').html();
        var d5 = $('#d5').html();

        totaal = parseInt(d1) + parseInt(d2) + parseInt(d3) + parseInt(d4) + parseInt(d5);

        $('#totaal').html(totaal);

        $('#d1').click(function ()
        {
            //When i click on dice 1 it needs to lock
            $('#d1').css('background-color', 'grey');
        });

    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Javascript opdracht Yahtzee</h1>
            <button id="werp1" type="button" name="werp" >Gooi</button>
            <div id="d1" class="dobbelsteen">5</div>
            <div id="d2" class="dobbelsteen">4</div>
            <div id="d3" class="dobbelsteen">3</div>
            <div id="d4" class="dobbelsteen">2</div>
            <div id="d5" class="dobbelsteen">1</div>
            <div id="totaal"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Add a class on the dice on click, then roll only the ones that don't have the class.

Comment: @Sami Thanks, it works but can i do it in a faster way otherwise i need to print out 6 times for each dice add class.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function randomGetal() {
  var getal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
  return getal;
}

function stopElem() {
  var totaal = 0;
  $('.dobbelsteen').not('.not-roll').each(function() {
    $(this).html(randomGetal());
    totaal += parseInt($(this).html());
  })
  $('#totaal').html(totaal);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#werp1').click(function() {

    stopElem();

  });
  $('.dobbelsteen').click(function() {
    //When i click on dice 1 it needs to lock
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray').addClass('not-roll');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Javascript opdracht Yahtzee</h1>
    <button id="werp1" type="button" name="werp">Gooi</button>
    <div id="d1" class="dobbelsteen">5</div>
    <div id="d2" class="dobbelsteen">4</div>
    <div id="d3" class="dobbelsteen">3</div>
    <div id="d4" class="dobbelsteen">2</div>
    <div id="d5" class="dobbelsteen">1</div>
    <div id="totaal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfect, but can you explain the function stop to me? So i can learn from it

Comment: @KipVerslaafde There's not much in stopElem() the main change is adding a class with the clicked element and exclude it in stopElem() .$(this).css('background-color', 'gray').addClass('not-roll');

Answer (score 1):

Add a `class` to the clicked element and do the rest based on that.

```js
function randomGetal() {
    var getal = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    return getal;
  }
  // bind click event or the elemnts, since only want to fire once use `one()` method
var $div = $('#d1,#d2,#d3,#d4,#d5').one('click', function() {
  // add class to the elemnt
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#werp1').click(function() {
    // initialize variable for total
    var tot = 0;
    // iterate  over div
    $div.html(function(i, v) {
        // update text content if not selected
        if (!$(this).hasClass('selected'))
          v = randomGetal();
        // parse and add with total
        tot += parseInt(v, 10);
        // return and update the html content
        return v;
      })
      // remove the attached event hanler if all elements are selected
    if (!$div.not('selected').length) $(this).off('click');
    // update the total value 
    $('#totaal').html(tot);
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: grey
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Javascript opdracht Yahtzee</h1>
    <button id="werp1" type="button" name="werp">Gooi</button>
    <div id="d1" class="dobbelsteen">5</div>
    <div id="d2" class="dobbelsteen">4</div>
    <div id="d3" class="dobbelsteen">3</div>
    <div id="d4" class="dobbelsteen">2</div>
    <div id="d5" class="dobbelsteen">1</div>
    <div id="totaal"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```